Why is exit code reset after negated if expression
I recently stumbled upon something that doesn't seem to make sense:
echo "Hit ENTER to continue or CTRL+D to abort."
read -s -t 3 || {
    case $? in
        0) echo "should not occur"; ;;
        1) echo "CTRL+D"; ;;
        *) echo "Timeout"; ;;
    esac
}

works as expected (both CTRL+D/EOF and timeout are caught), but
echo "Hit ENTER to continue or CTRL+D to abort."
if ! read -s -t 3; then
    case $? in
        0) echo "should not occur"; ;;
        1) echo "CTRL+D"; ;;
        *) echo "Timeout"; ;;
    esac
fi

does NOT work as expected ($? is always 0).
Why (and how) is $? reset before if's body is being executed?
Interestingly enough, the inverted construct:
echo "Hit ENTER to continue or CTRL+D to abort."
if read -s -t 3; then
    :
else
    case $? in
        0) echo "should not occur"; ;;
        1) echo "CTRL+D"; ;;
        *) echo "Timeout"; ;;
    esac
fi

does work as expected. That indicates that ! might be responsible, but I couldn't find any documentation to back that up.
Bash version: 5.1.16

How would you ever get the "timeout" branch followed after ! inverts, changing anything nonzero to 0 and 0 to 1?

The exclamation mark is not a part of the if command, it negates the exit status of the pipeline following it. Try ! false; echo $? and you'll see. You can access the exit values of pipeline components through the PIPESTATUS array if you have to.

@oguzismail You should turn that into an answer or expand on the one posted by axiac:
(1) ! <command> constitutes a pipeline (that was the part that eluded me)
(2) ! in a pipeline negates a command's return code (as described by the documentation, easy to spot once you know that you're actually dealing with a pipeline)
(3) PIPESTATUS can used to access the command's return code (nice addition/solution)

! does not reset the exit code. It negates the exit code of the command that follows and produces the final exit code of the pipeline.
It is explained in section "3.2.3 Pipelines" of Bash documentation (it is also on man bash but without section numbers).

A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&.
The format for a pipeline is
[time [-p]] [!] command1 [ | or |& command2 ] ...

...
The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline [...]. If the reserved word ! precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status as described above.

! is not part of the syntax of the if statement. The syntax of the if statement is:
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi

A list of commands is a sequence or one or more pipelines, separated by one of the operators ;, &, &&, or ||. Usually, a single pipeline is used to describe the condition in an if statement.
Because ! is part of a pipeline, the results that you get can also be described without using an if statement:
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo $?
0

$ ! echo foo
foo
$ echo $?
1

Update
As user @oguz-ismail describes in a comment on the question, the array variable PIPESTATUS contains a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).
Let's try some examples:
$ echo foo | cat; echo "${#PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
2

The pipeline contains two commands, the array PIPESTATUS contains two items (${#X[@]} is the number of items in the array variable X).
$ echo foo | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
0 0

Both commands exit successfully.
$ echo foo | cat; echo -e "$?\n" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
0
 0 0

The pipeline completed successfully (the second line, printed by $?), each command completed successfully ("${PIPESTATUS[@]}" produces the items of PIPESTATUS as separate parameters for echo).
$ ! echo foo | cat; echo -e "$?\n" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
1
 0 0

Same as above, but because of !, the pipeline exit status is 1.
Let's try something a bit more complex:
$ { echo foo; exit 2; } | { cat ; exit 7; }; echo -e "$?\n" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
7
 2 7

There are two compound commands (grouping), with exit codes 2 and 7. The exit code of the pipeline is the exit code of the last command (7), the exit codes of all commands are listed from PIPESTATUS.
One last example:
$ ! { echo foo; exit 2; } | { cat ; exit 7; }; echo -e "$?\n" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
foo
0
 2 7

The ! in front negates the pipeline result (7, which is false, is turned to 0, meaning true), the rest is as before.

Today I learned about PIPESTATUS. Thank you @oguz-ismail for pointing it out in your comment to the question. Thank you @fonic for asking me to include it in the answer.

I'll accept this, although oguz ismail posted the same info (as a comment) before your answer. How about you add his remarks regarding PIPESTATUS (see comments below question)?

@Fonic I wrote my answer based on my previous knowledge about how the pipelines work. I didn't know about PIPESTATUS (probably I never needed this functionality). Today I learned about it, from your comment. I updated the answer to include this information. Thank you.
